# htaccess want to add www without affecting subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

This is what I have in htaccess and all my other pages show 404 errors, the homepage works but doesn't have the www added.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1[R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

[Live site link](http://bit.ly/1CZqrN4)

Any help is appreciated! I'm going crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^macmetro\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks buddy, will it add the www infront of the main domain?

Comment: do you mind sending me the answer with the www added? I am not a developer. :(

Comment: still didn't work, no www and 404 errors are still there :(

Comment: I FEEL SO DUMB, THE HTACCESS FILE DID NOT HAVE A PERIOD BEFORE THE FILE NAME. IT WORKS NOW !! THANKS

Comment: Ok done, I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.